# RestAssured oAuth2 http status code 401

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, rest-assured

I'm trying to implement integration test using RestAssured library and Spring MVC REST oAuth2 secured endpoint.

This is my test:

```
@Test
public void testCreateDecision() throws Exception {
    File createDecisionJsonFile = ResourceUtils.getFile(getClass().getResource("/json/decisions/create-decision.json"));

    // @formatter:off
    final String createDecisionRequest = FileUtils.readFileToString(createDecisionJsonFile)
            .replace("{{name}}", "Test decision name")
            .replace("{{description}}", "Test decision description");
    // @formatter:on

    String accessToken = getAccessToken("user", "user");

    // @formatter:off
    given()
        .auth()
        .oauth2(accessToken, OAuthSignature.HEADER)
        .body(createDecisionRequest)
        .contentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    .when()
        .post(format("http://localhost:%d/api/v1.0/decisions/create", port))
    .then()
        .statusCode(200)
        .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
        .body("id", notNullValue())
        .body("createDate", notNullValue());
    // @formatter:on

}
```

The accessToken is valid but I'm continuously getting 401 http code.
What could be wrong with my code ?

Comment: I don't know how rest assured works under the covers but you can see what is happening in Spring Security by enabling DEBUG logging (org.springframework.security). Probably it will tell you that the header is missing or malformed.

Comment: Thanks! I think, I have found a similar issue https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/issues/detail?id=354 Is there some kind of workaround based on Restassured library in order to avoid this issue ?

Comment: I would assume you can set a header. Just set "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know this is an old post, but just wanted to document this in case someone else needed the answer. 
I was able to implement using the following format:

First retrieve the token (in my case I did not store user tokens, jut got them before each test)

```
// we need to get the oauth token before we can perform the request
private void authenticateUser(String username, String password) {

    String response =
            given()
                .parameters("username", username, "password", password, 
                           "grant_type", "password", "scope", "read write", 
                           "client_id", "clientapp", "client_secret", "123456")
                .auth()
                .preemptive()
                .basic("clientapp","123456")
            .when()
                .post("/oauth/token")
                .asString();

    JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(response);
    accessToken = jsonPath.getString("access_token");
}
```

And them on the test I used the retrieved token:

```
@Test
public void testGetUserDefaultUserOwner() {


    authenticateUser(testData.user1.getLogin(), "1");

    User user = 
        given()
            .auth().oauth2(accessToken)
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .accept(ContentType.JSON)
        .expect()
            .log().all()
            .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value())
        .when()
            .get(USER_RESOURCE, testData.user1.getId())
            .as(User.class);

    assertThat(user).isEqualTo(testData.user1);
}
```

I am using Restassured and AssertJ for the tests, and SpringBoot with OAuth2 for the Rest APIs.

Answer (score 1):

I have reimplemented my test using OAuth2RestTemplate:

```
ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();

resourceDetails.setUsername("user");
resourceDetails.setPassword("user");
resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(format("http://localhost:%d/oauth/token", port));
resourceDetails.setClientId("clientapp");
resourceDetails.setClientSecret("123456");
resourceDetails.setGrantType("password");
resourceDetails.setScope(asList("read", "write"));

DefaultOAuth2ClientContext clientContext = new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext();

OAuth2RestTemplate auth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails, clientContext);
auth2RestTemplate.setMessageConverters(asList(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()));

Assert.assertNotNull(auth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken());

DecisionRequest decisionRequest = new DecisionRequest(name, description, parentDecisionId);

auth2RestTemplate.postForObject(format("http://localhost:%d/api/v1.0/decisions/create", port), decisionRequest, Decision.class);
```

Answer (score -2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://example.com/404/index.html">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```