# Spring oauth2 and integration tests

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, integration-testing, rest-assured

Need a help with integration tests for Oauth2 client.

**Setup:**

- **Client** with protected UI and API
- **Authentication server** where all
  password validation done and access token retrieved

**Integration test:**

- rest-assured used for end-point testing
- before implementing Oauth2 tests worked fine

**Ole test example:**

```
        given().auth()
           .preemptive()
           .basic(USER_EMAIL,PASSWORD) <-- this not valid any more
           .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
           .when()
           .pathParam("id","123")
           .delete(PROFILE_FIELD_BASE_URL)
           .andReturn()
           .body();
```

**Question:**

- how I can make this tests work again?
- How res-assured setup should be changed to support oauth2?
- Do I need to mock **Authentication server** or can I inject/mock security context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you were shown is only and only for basic auth and for using the rest assured for OAuth, in general, you have to change that code. From REST Assured [github page](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/blob/master/examples/rest-assured-itest-java/src/test/java/io/restassured/itest/java/OAuthITest.java) you can see following two exaples:

```
    @Test public void
oauth2_works_with_preemptive_header_signing() {
    final String accessToken = "accessToken";

    given().
            auth().preemptive().oauth2(accessToken).
            filter(new Filter() {
                public Response filter(FilterableRequestSpecification requestSpec, FilterableResponseSpecification responseSpec, FilterContext ctx) {
                    assertThat(requestSpec.getHeaders().getValue("Authorization"), equalTo("Bearer "+accessToken));
                    return new ResponseBuilder().setBody("ok").setStatusCode(200).build();
                }
            }).
    when().
            get("/somewhere").
    then().
            statusCode(200);
}

@Test public void
oauth2_works_with_non_preemptive_header_signing() {
    final String accessToken = "accessToken";

    given().
            auth().oauth2(accessToken).
            filter(new Filter() {
                public Response filter(FilterableRequestSpecification requestSpec, FilterableResponseSpecification responseSpec, FilterContext ctx) {
                    AuthenticationScheme scheme = requestSpec.getAuthenticationScheme();
                    assertThat(scheme, instanceOf(PreemptiveOAuth2HeaderScheme.class));
                    assertThat(((PreemptiveOAuth2HeaderScheme) scheme).getAccessToken(), equalTo(accessToken));
                    return new ResponseBuilder().setBody("ok").setStatusCode(200).build();
                }
            }).
    when().
            get("/somewhere").
    then().
            statusCode(200);
}
```

and as the other example, you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155161/restassured-oauth2-http-status-code-401).